# How do I play music using MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

Can any one suggest me how to play the music using MPMusicPlayerController in my application.

Anyone's help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `MPMediaPickerController` so you can choose some music from the iPod,
then in the `mediaPicker:didPickMediaItems:` call back you do this:

```
MPMusicPlayerController* playa;
playa = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
[playa setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
[playa play];
```

Comment: thank you for you answear, but how can I create a mediaItemCollection from files or urls on the local app?

Comment: I can't see any way to do it. You probably can't. If you don't want audio from the iPod library, you should use AVAudioPlayer. The iPhone music APIs are not very orthogonal.