# Is it possible to get data or songs of music player in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, media-player

Hello first of all I am new in iPhone,

I want access all songs in my application. Is this posible to get all songs ?

Thank you very much. May be it's easy for you but for me it's hard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need the Media Player framework:

- MPMediaLibrary, MPMediaQuery, etc.
- iPod Library Access Programming Guide

Actual example taken from the docs:

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Logging items from a generic query...");
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSLog (@"%@", songTitle);
}
```

Comment: i am not getting . one line before you alloc and in next line [everything items];
 it will give me all items ?

Comment: so it is method in which i will get all songs ?

Comment: Yes, `items` is a method of `MPMediaQuery` instance that return all matching elements. Experiment with the different kind of queries. Check the docs (links will broke, just search in your local Xcode docs).

Comment: @djromero it is Possible to get the song and save it to my app(document directory)? please help me

Comment: @MohitPopat I guess it can be done with the AV framework. Look around, there must be questions in SO or somewhere else. If not, ask a proper question, is not a subject that can be addressed in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

[This tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-music-library-access/) might help you as well.

Comment: ya this is nice. wow its give me all things. not might it help me a lot. i want to vote you but its says require 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You need the Media Player framework:

Its easy you have to use "MPMusicPlayerController" this class.

By this thing you will find all things.

for more info see 
[How do I play music using MPMusicPlayerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288747/how-do-i-play-music-using-mpmusicplayercontroller)